# How to remove the "x" (close) symbol from mapbox pop up

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a mapbox marker pop up and i want to remove the "x"(close) symbol as it is over my text. I have searched and couldn't find a solution for this. Thanks for reading.

This is how it looks now.
[image: marker_popup]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `closebutton = false`

Like:

```
this.#popup = new Popup({
            closeButton: false,//<----
            closeOnClick: false,
            closeOnMove: true,
            maxWidth: "auto"
        });
```

[Read here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/markers/#popup)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You can style your popups using CSS:

```css
    .mapboxgl-popup-close-button{
      display: none;
     }
    .mapboxgl-popup-content{
      font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
      padding: 0;
      width: 180px;
     }
    .mapboxgl-popup-content-wrapper{
      padding: 1%;
     }
```